# Why is JavaScript correctly calculating my variable yet displays it as undefined in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, function, dom

And how do I get it to display the number, not undefined?

It's a tipping app. The user inputs the price of whatever it is they bought (pizza, haircut, etc.) in `#price`, then `calcTip()` calculates the tip, sends it over to `calcTotal()` which calculates the total, and sends it over to `displayAmounts()`.

I don't know exactly what happens, but something messes up with the variable `tip`. `calcTip()` works correctly and calculates the tip amount successfully. I know this because the JavaScript console displays the amount when I input `tip;`. However, on the page, `#tipSpan` displays the tip as undefined.

What baffles me most is that the variable `total` works perfectly fine.

Does anyone know what might be going on or how I can fix it?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Tipping App</title>
    <style>
        <!-- Temporary -->
        #error {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Tipping App</h1>
        </header>

        <section>
            <div class="price">
                <h2>Price Information</h2>
                <label for="priceInput">Enter the price below!</label><input id="priceInput" type="text"><button id="calcButton">Calculate the Tip</button>
                <p id="error">Error: You need to enter the cost!<br><br>Use only numbers and decimal points, no currency symbols or letters.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="tipContainer" class="tip">
                <h2>Tip Information</h2>
                <p id="tipPara">Your tip should be... <span>$<span id="tipSpan"></span></span></p>
            </div>

            <div id="totalContainer" class="total">
                <h2>Total Information</h2>
                <p id="totalPara">Your total is... <span>$<span id="totalSpan"></span></span></p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
///// VARIABLES
//////////////////////////////

var priceInput = document.getElementById("priceInput");
var calcButton = document.getElementById("calcButton");
var error = document.getElementById("error");
var tipContainer = document.getElementById("tipContainer");
var tipPara = document.getElementById("tipPara");
var tipSpan = document.getElementById("tipSpan");
var totalContainer = document.getElementById("totalContainer");
var totalPara = document.getElementById("totalPara");
var totalSpan = document.getElementById("totalSpan");

var tip;
var total;

///// FUNCTIONS
//////////////////////////////

function calcTip() {
    var price = priceInput.value; // This is the price the user inputs
    var minTip = (Math.ceil(price * .15)); // Calculates a 15% tip rounded up to the nearest dollar
    var maxTip = (price * .2); // Calculates a 20% tip

    if (isNaN(price) || price === "") {
        // If the user doesn't enter a number
        // Or doesn't enter anything,
        // Then display the error message
        error.style.display = "block";
        return;
    } else {
        error.style.display = "none";
        if (maxTip < minTip) {
            // If the 20% tip is less than the 15% rounded tip,
            // Then let's go with that 20% tip
            calcTotal(price, maxTip);
            tip = maxTip;
        } else {
            // Otherwise, let's just do the 15%
            calcTotal(price, minTip);
            tip = minTip;
        };
    };
};

function calcTotal(price, tip) {
    // Add the price and the tip together to yield the total
    price = parseInt(price);
    tip = parseInt(tip);
    total = (price + tip);
    displayAmounts();
}

function displayAmounts() {
    // Update the page to display the tip and the total to the user
    tipContainer.style.display = "block";
    totalContainer.style.display = "block";
    tipSpan.innerText = tip;
    totalSpan.innerText = total;
}

///// EVENTS
//////////////////////////////

calcButton.addEventListener("click", calcTip);
```

Also, unrelated, but does my JavaScript look good? Is it clean code? I hope to find a web development job in the near future, and I know I need to be good at JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mezoqiyenu/1/edit?js,output)**

Update the function arguments

```
function calcTotal(price, maxTip) {
    // Add the price and the tip together to yield the total
    price = parseInt(price);
    tip = parseInt(maxTip);
    total = (price + tip);
    displayAmounts();
}
```

Here the argument `tip` is overriding the global variable. Replace it to `maxTip` as you call.

Comment: But I have `var tip;` above all of the functions in the `// VARIABLES` section.

Comment: The variable is not set before you call calcTotal. So it's undefined

Comment: The tip in calcTotal is local variable and not global

Comment: Updated the answer. It;s because the local argument tip is overriding the global variable

Comment: I defined `var tip;` as a global variable (outside of any functions). And I used `tip` inside the `calcTip()` function, but without using the `var` keyword. From what I understand, this means that `tip` inside the function will be the global variable (if I had used `var tip;` inside the function, then it would have been a local variable that would be undefined).

Comment: No. The tip inside the calcTotal(price, tip) will always refer to the local variable tip which is available via the argument. You can try in your console as well. When you pass arguments you won't use var keyword in front of them. They are by default local variables

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you're saying. It's not looking at the `tip` global variable, just the argument in `calcTotal(price, tip)`. Thanks! I don't think putting `maxTip` as an argument is a good idea because it's inevitable that `minTip` will have to go there in some instances, but I'm going to play around with the variables to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your method definition so it passes the values in:

`displayAmounts();` should become `displayAmounts(tip, total);`

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3e01a93y/).

Also you should use `parseFloat` rather than `parseInt` assuming you'll want to be more accurate than whole numbers.

Comment: So simple! I have no idea why `total` was fine, but `tip` was acting weird, but it works! I'll accept your answer when it lets me in a few minutes.

Comment: Actually the problem is not related to that. It's a global variable. Instead if you had just changed the argument name in calcTotal() function it would have worked well. Just the local variable has overridden the global variable value.

Answer (score 0):

1) In function displayAmounts, pass parameters tip & total

2) Instead of

tipSpan.innerText = tip,

TRY WITH

tipSpan.innerHTML = tip;

and same for total ,

use totalSpan.innerHTML = total

instead of

totalSpan.innerText ;

Then it should work

Answer (score 0):

Just a small mistake!

Instead of:

```
calcTotal(price, minTip);
tip = minTip;
```

Do:

```
tip = minTip;
calcTotal(price, minTip);
```

This way tip is calculated before displayAmounts is run.

Abut your code:

This is fine with just getting started. I recommend going through w3school's [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) on javascript. The more you use javascript, the better you will get.

If you want a learning path I would recommend taking, let me know.

Comment: That seemed to make sense, but then it displayed `total` as `NaN`.

Comment: Ah, one more thing, change where you parse the string to the beginning of your code

var price = parseFloat(priceInput.value);

and then remove the other 2 instances  of parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

innerText works only on IE. [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is W3C-compliant, but if you want your code to be standards compliant and cross-browser safe you should use this:

```
while( tipSpan.firstChild ) {
    tipSpan.removeChild( tipSpan.firstChild );
}
tipSpan.appendChild( document.createTextNode(tip) );
```

Do this for totalSpan also.

Comment: Yeah, I can see now that I was wrong to use `.innerText`. It doesn't work in Firefox. But why not just use `.innerHTML`?

Comment: .innerHTML its not cross-browser safe. Besides, createTextNode escapes node content so you dont have to worry about that.